# Как определить присутствует ли операция boxing в c#?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, оптимизация

В общем есть такой код:

```
public class AccountProcessor
{
    // ToDo Реализовать без копирования и боксинга
    public decimal Calculate(BankAccount bankAccount)
    {
        return CalculateOperation(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation1(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation1(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation2(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation2(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount)
               +
               CalculateOperation(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation1(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation1(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation2(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation2(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount)
               +
               CalculateOperation(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation1(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation1(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation2(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation2(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount.LastOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount.PreviousOperation) +
               CalculateOperation3(bankAccount);
    }

    private decimal CalculateOperation(BankOperation bankOperation)
    {
        // Some calculation code
        return bankOperation.OperationInfo0;
    }

    private decimal CalculateOperation1(BankOperation bankOperation)
    {
        // Some calculation code
        return bankOperation.OperationInfo1;
    }

    private decimal CalculateOperation2(BankOperation bankOperation)
    {
        // Some calculation code
        return bankOperation.OperationInfo2;
    }

    private decimal CalculateOperation3(ITotalAmount bankOperation)
    {
        // Some calculation code
        return bankOperation.TotalAmount;
    }
}


public struct BankAccount : ITotalAmount
{
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public BankOperation LastOperation { get; set; }
    public BankOperation PreviousOperation { get; set; }
}

public interface ITotalAmount
{
    decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
}

public struct BankOperation : ITotalAmount
{
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    public long Rubles { get; set; }

    public short Kopeks { get; set; }

    public long RublesBeforeOperation { get; set; }

    public short KopeksBeforeOperation { get; set; }

    public long RublesAfterOperation { get; set; }

    public short KopeksAfterOperation { get; set; }

    public long OperationInfo0 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo1 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo2 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo3 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo4 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo5 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo6 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo7 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo8 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo9 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo10 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo11 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo12 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo13 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo14 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo15 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo16 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo17 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo18 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo19 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo20 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo21 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo22 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo23 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo24 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo25 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo26 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo27 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo28 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo29 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo30 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo31 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo32 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo33 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo34 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo35 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo36 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo37 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo38 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo39 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo40 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo41 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo42 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo43 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo44 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo45 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo46 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo47 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo48 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo49 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo50 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo51 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo52 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo53 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo54 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo55 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo56 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo57 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo58 { get; set; }
    public long OperationInfo59 { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно было реализовать метод CalculatePerformed, который делал бы то же самое, но без копирования и боксинга. Вот мое решение:

```
public decimal CalculatePerformed(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    return CalculateLastOperationPerformed(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed1(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed1(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed2(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed2(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateAccountOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount)
           +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed1(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed1(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed2(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed2(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateAccountOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount)
           +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed1(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed1(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed2(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed2(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateLastOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount) +
           CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount) +
           CalculateAccountOperationPerformed3(in bankAccount);
}

private decimal CalculateLastOperationPerformed(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.LastOperation.OperationInfo0;
}

private decimal CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.PreviousOperation.OperationInfo0;
}

private decimal CalculateLastOperationPerformed1(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.LastOperation.OperationInfo1;
}

private decimal CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed1(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.PreviousOperation.OperationInfo1;
}

private decimal CalculateLastOperationPerformed2(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.LastOperation.OperationInfo2;
}

private decimal CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed2(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.PreviousOperation.OperationInfo2;
}

private decimal CalculateLastOperationPerformed3(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.LastOperation.TotalAmount;
}

private decimal CalculatePreviousOperationPerformed3(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.PreviousOperation.TotalAmount;
}

private decimal CalculateAccountOperationPerformed3(in BankAccount bankAccount)
{
    // Some calculation code
    return bankAccount.TotalAmount;
}
```

Как проверить что нет операции боксинга? Только через IL код или еще как нибудь можно? И да, на сколько мое решение хорошее, можно ли было сделать лучше и как?
Бенчмарк:

```
// Результаты
// |             Method |       Mean |    Error |  StdDev | Rank |   Gen0 | Allocated |
// |------------------- |-----------:|---------:|--------:|-----:|-------:|----------:|
// | CalculatePerformed |   833.5 ns |  7.99 ns | 7.48 ns |    1 |      - |         - |
// |          Calculate | 2,021.7 ns | 10.17 ns | 8.49 ns |    2 | 3.2120 |    6720 B |
```

Comment: Само существование структуры BankOperation с дохренелионом полей - потенциальная проблема в производительности. Такие вещи надо делать классами.

Comment: Но если уж делать её структурой - ни в коем случае не прячьте такое в автосвойство. Такие тяжёлые структуры можно делать только нормальными полями.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я это понимаю, просто задание заключается именно в том, что я описал, дабы увидеть на бенчмарках разницу в производительности

Comment: Тогда вы должны сделать LastOperation и PreviousOperation полями, иначе копирования не избежать. А если их тоже нельзя делать полями - то надо минимизировать число обращений к ним, например вынеся их в локальную переменную.

Comment: [Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer](https://github.com/Microsoft/RoslynClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer) или его форк [ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=FonsSonnemans.ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer)

Comment: @PavelMayorov так если я сделаю их полями, копирование ведь все равно будет, так как это структуры. Или вы имеете ввиду когда использую in?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, попробую. А если вот у меня на руках есть IL код, что я там должен увидеть, чтобы понять что боксинг есть? Просто не совсем разбираюсь в IL командах

Comment: @Андрей разумеется, поля надо комбинировать с in. Но проблема не в in, проблема в том что при использовании свойств вы в принципе не можете избежать копирования при каждом обращении.

Comment: @PavelMayorov извините, я первый раз это слышу. Можете пожалуйста пояснить, или источник дать почитать, интересно стало

Comment: @Андрей смотрите, автосвойство - это сахар для методов. Структуры передаются по значению. Передача по значению - это копирование.

Comment: @PavelMayorov так а что изменилось бы, если бы это были просто поля? Эти поля все равно были бы типом структуры, и все равно копировались бы. Так какая разница тогда не могу понять?

Comment: Поля доступны по ссылке, а не только по значению.  Вы можете передать в метод `ref/in x.Foo` если Foo - поле, но не можете если это автосвойство. (Того же эффекта можно добиться если сделать свойство, возвращающее ссылку - но использовать поле проще)

Comment: @PavelMayorov все, я понял, спасибо за объяснения!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боксинг влечёт за собой объект. По определению. А если боксинга нет - ну значит и объекта нет.

Пользуйте множество методов из System.GС и всякие связанные с ним GCMemoryInfo. Это всё можно запустить перед тестом, и после теста. И получить абсолютно все данные по количеству объектов, сколько они занимают памяти и так далее. Если у вас боксинг идёт - так у вас количество объектов будет увеличиваться и GC это покажет, и использование памяти этими объектами тоже покажет, и так далее. А если объектов нет - ну значит и боксинга нет.

И на самом деле это всё нужно смотреть в отладчиках, они в общем то простые и показывают объекты. Вплоть до какого нибудь кучерявого вин-дбг, и даже там можно увидеть хип, и как он растёт (если растёт).

И на самом деле, даже обычный бенч от майкрософта показывает боксинг. Ну т.е. если вы запустили бенч и увидели расход памяти - это и есть боксинг. Которого быть не должно. И если ваш тестируемый метод не пользует память на куче - это и значит что боксинга нету (в вашем случае нету).

Ваше решение (в первом простейшем грубом приближении) тогда хорошее, когда оно исполняется как минимум в два раза быстрее чем было, иначе оптимизации мало чего дают. И второе, может быть более существенное - это ваше решение потребляет сильно меньше памяти на куче, т.е. вы не плодите объекты. Условно говоря у вас был расход на куче 4Кб, стал 32б - вот это хорошо, это замечательно. А совсем хорошо когда строго 0б, это когда вы кучу не используете вообще.

Совсем дикий способ, и он не всегда показывает то что вам нужно. В идеале вы запускаете приложение, и посмотрите на память в банальном диспетчере задач. Вы теребонькаете ваше приложение, и память ДОЛЖНА СТОЯТЬ. Т.е. она вообще не должна меняться. Условно говоря как было например 8 232 Кб - вот так оно и должно быть. Вы пользуете вашу программу, а память стоит. Вообще не меняется. Никак. Это то, к чему вы должны прийти. В идеале.

Вы показали некий код, там структуры весьма длинные. И размер этих структур - тривиально считаем. Впрочем там зачем то short используется, и с выравниванием будут проблемы, но размер посчитать (хотя бы прикинуть размер - всегда можно). Так вот ваши большие структуры на тестах будут отжырать память вёдрами (в случае боксинга), запустите миллион структур - они улетят в хип, и вы увидите что память скачет как бешаная. Это и есть боксинг (в вашем конкретном случае). Это когда вы плодите множество объектов (дахрилион), а коллектор их подчищает за вами. И всё это выглядит циклически, как пила. Пачка объектов - очистка - пачка объектов - очистка. Это можно увидеть даже в диспетчере задач (при условии если много объектов).

Comment: Добавил результат бэнчмарка методов

Comment: О! Отлично! Стало работать быстрее, и это не суть. Расход памяти на хипе нулевой - и значит что боксинга нет. При этом. Тут есть подводные камни. Вам в некотором смысле - повезло. Потому что вы отлавливаете боксинг на структурах. Но может быть так, что у вас могут быть не структуры, а объекты. И уже объекты или их "внутренности" - боксятся. И это отловить сложнее. Суть на примере. Пусть есть словарь и он на объектах. И по какому то алгоритму словарь теребонькается, и слегка "плодит" объекты, и это нормально, так устроен алгоритм, так задумано, бенч это покажет, и расход памяти на хипе покажет.

Comment: И ключевое здесь то, что нужно разобраться в алгоритме и прикинуть сколько "приплода" объектов накарячивает алгоритм. Условно представьте что алгоритм это 200 объектов и прирост должен быть 10, но в бенчмарке вы видите не 10 а 100. Откуда "лишние" объекты появляются? Это может быть боксинг. Но тут проблема в том, что бенч вам не покажет "деление" на нужное и не нужное, он вам покажет "общий приплод", а откуда всё это лезет - это как говорится - разбирайтесь сами. Я к тому, что объекты это не всегда зло, и они могут быть. И в этой общей сумме объектов как раз таки и могут быть "лишние" объекты.